# flex-wrap isn't wrapping inside the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: my result][image: my code][image: this is the result he gets][image: this is my instructor's code]Very new to css and html, and am following along a udemy course and though I've followed along the instructor's code to a tee, my flex-wrap just isn't wrapping inside the container.  Here's what I have so far:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  background-color: #003049;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid #003049;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Let's Play With Flexbox</h1>

<section id="container">
  <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
</section>
```

when i set it to flex-wrap: nowrap; it seems to be fine and stays within #container. But when I change it to flex-wrap: wrap; or flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; the colored div boxes go outside #container. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your `#container` div has a fixed height of `500px` which the browser will respect and not break. Setting it to `height: 100%` will allow the container to change height as required.

```
#container {
    background-color: #003049;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid #003049;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for the answer. I thought the whole purpose of flex-boxes was so that the contents inside would be "flexible" and adjust themselves to the containers they were put into.  When the instructor ran his code on udemy, the contents inside the container became smaller, rather than increase the size of the container itself.  But seeing the other answers, that's what seems to be the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set a height. Let the browser render it for you.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  background-color: #003049;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid #003049;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Let's Play With Flexbox</h1>

<section id="container">
  <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
  <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. is there a way that I can have the contents inside #container without changing the size of the #container itself?

Comment: @YoonCho What do you mean by "have the contents inside... without changing the size"?

Comment: So I believe the lesson of this section in my udemy course is to have the #container be a set height, and by using flex-wrap, the contents inside the #container will adjust themselves to be able to fit inside it. The instructor kept his #container to a set height of 500px, and it seemed the divs inside the container changed their dimensions to be able to fit inside

Comment: @YoonCho If you set the height to `500px` it is wrapping properly. If it wasn't they would be on the same row. I'm not sure what your desired outcome is. A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: thanks again, I have edited my original post with screenshots, though they seem a bit out of order.  1st pic is my result when opening the html file. 2nd is a screenshot of the css code. 3rd is a screenshot of my instructor's result of his html file. 4th is his screenshot of his css code.  thanks again so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

1.) Add `overflow-y: auto;` to the flex-container to allow its contents to scroll inside it while its fixed height is kept:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    background-color: #003049;
    width: 90%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid #003049;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}

#container div{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Let's Play With Flexbox</h1>

<section id="container">
    <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
</section>
```

2.) Or, as a second solution, just erase the `heigth` setting for the flex container, which will set its height to `auto` , allowing it to grow as needed:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    background-color: #003049;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid #003049;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}

#container div{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Let's Play With Flexbox</h1>

<section id="container">
    <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
</section>
```